# Hide Treemap labels for smaller nodes in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

Is there a setting for hiding the label for smaller treemap nodes?  I would like to prevent the labels from showing if they are larger than the area of the node.

[image: Treemap with problem nodes where the label is larger than the area of the node (shown here)]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out that I just needed to upgrade to a newer version of highcharts to solve this.

Comment: upgrade to which version?

Comment: I'm on Highcharts JS v4.2.3 (2016-02-08) right now and have not encountered this problem.  I know that it was resolved in earlier versions as well but I'm not certain exactly when it was fixed.